# How to link two css properties together?

Tags: css, html, height

I have one div that has a dynamic height and another div that is a float. Is there a way in css I can link div2's height with the height of div1?

Comment: define link. Use values for your example

Comment: Sadly, the only sane way to achieve this is to use tables, or `display: table-*` properties (which somehow feels equally silly)

Comment: Do you mean you want a second div tag to mirror the height of the dynamic first div tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's that you want : http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/08/equal-height-columns-using-borders-and-negative-margins-with-css/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you can wrap both divs in a 3rd div(wrapper) and then set the height of div2 to 100%

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
  </div>
  <div style="clear: right"></div>
</div>
```

.div2 { float: right; height: 100% }